# How to make an item to appear for a short time (Either Javascript or CSS)

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, css-transitions

In a part of my there is a button that might not be very visible by users, so I would like to add an item (such as an email like "Browse here") to appear on-load and disappear after the user press the related button.  I think it can be done by CSS animation but hot to remove it by pressing the button?! So Maybe Javascript.

So Any idea?
Thanks.

[image]

Comment: You want JavaScript instead. Not Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use a simple css if its a link

```
a:visited{
   display: none;
}
```

other wise a good jquery

```
$('button').click( function(){ $(this).toggle() ));
```

and with javascript

```
<input type='button' onclick='hide(this);' />

function hide(clickedButton) {
   clickedButton.style.display = "none";
}
```

or css and javascript

```
<input type='button' onclick='hide(this);' />

.hidden{
     display:none;
}

function hide(clickedButton) {
   clickedButton.className = "hidden";
}
```

if they are two different buttons then jquery

```
$('#triggerButton').click( function(){ $('#hideButton').toggle() ));
```

and for the javascript

```
<input type='button' id = 'trigger'+ onclick='hide(this);' />

function hide(clickedButton) {
   document.getElementById('hide').style.display = "none";
}
```

or css and javascript

```
<input type='button' id = 'trigger' onclick='hide(this);' />

.hidden{
     display:none;
}

function hide(clickedButton) {
   document.getElementById('hide').className = "hidden";
}
```

hope that covers your question.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I tried to make what you wrote on JSFiddle. It does not work but I might made a mistake as I am not good at JS. http://jsfiddle.net/5wBuV/1/  Can you check it please?!

Comment: @AlexJj try this - http://jsfiddle.net/5wBuV/2/ - for hiding it and this - http://jsfiddle.net/5wBuV/3/ - for removing it

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know, you can add/remove any element of an HtML page with Javascript.

Add a button (see [link](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_createelement.asp)):

```
var btn = document.createElement("buttonId");
btn.innerHTML = "Click Me";
var divObj = document.getElementById("divId");
divObj.appendChild(btn);
```

Remove an item (see [link](http://w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_removechild.asp)):

```
var btn = document.getElementById("buttonId");
btn.parentNode.removeChild(btn);
```

I haven't check the code, but that would be my guess...

Another approach i can think of is that you create the element (like a div) and show it by default.

```
<div onClick="hideMe(this)">Browse here</div>
```

And then you create a Javascript function that sets "display" to "none" when you click it:

```
function hideMe(clicked_element){
   clicked_element.style.display = "none";
}
```